# SpringBoot + Lombok + MapStruct not working together

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I'm trying to configure SpringBoot (v2.6.2) with Lombok and MapStruct, already configured the maven compiler plugin and the lombok-mapstruct-binding (annotationProcessorPaths) but the lombok classes aren't being created:

pom.xml

```
*<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.knowledge</groupId>
    <artifactId>knowledge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>knowledge</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <version.mapstruct>1.4.1.Final</version.mapstruct>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                        </path>

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>*
```

Always getting an uninitialised variable error when trying to use DI:

> variable xxxx might not have been initialized

Comment: Just double checked everything, I was missing some intelliJ configurations.

Comment: is it error on IDE? or is it error after you run by maven? if it's error on IDE, maybe try to upgrade the lombok dependency and mapstruct, the older version doesn't support on newer IDE by default.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can also take a look at the accepted answer here [How to instruct Mapstruct to use lombok builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955000/how-to-instruct-mapstruct-to-use-lombok-builder) it's also the official mapstruct documentation https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_set_up

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                </path>

                <!-- additional annotation processor required as of Lombok 1.18.16 -->
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have working mapstruct + lombok with following versions

1. java 17
2. mapstruct 1.3.1.Final
3. spring boot 2.7.6
4. lombok 1.18.26
5. lombok-mapstruct-binding 0.2.0
6. maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1

Map struct > 1.4 versions dosent work with latest lombok versions. So in updated versions i have to downgrade mapstruct to make it work

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                        </path>

                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```