# MapStruct in Java Spring boot, can't be defined as Bean

Tags: java, spring

For testing purposes I wanted to use MapStruct in my test project. I have a rest POST endpoint where in postman a customer dto with 2 fields is provided, then I used ObjectMapper to convert it to my entity and eventually save it on postgres. That is ok and working, but now in parellel I want to use MapStruct. I get the error

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.project.dbproject.service.CustomerService required a bean of type 'com.project.dbproject.CustomerMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.dbproject.CustomerMapper' in your configuration.
```

This is my interface using MapStruct:

```
package com.project.dbproject;

import com.project.dbproject.model.entity.Customer;
import com.project.dbproject.model.entity.dto.CustomerDTO;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {

    Customer customerDTOToCustomer (CustomerDTO customer);
}
```

This is my SpringBootApplication

```
package com.project.dbproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan("com.project.dbproject")
public class DbprojectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DbprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my service

```
package com.project.dbproject.service;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.project.dbproject.CustomerMapper;
import com.project.dbproject.model.entity.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.project.dbproject.model.entity.Customer;
import com.project.dbproject.repository.CustomerRepository;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CustomerService {


    @Autowired
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;



    @Transactional
    public Customer addNewCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {

        log.info("the dto {}", customerDTO);
        Customer customer = objectMapper.convertValue(customerDTO, Customer.class);
        log.info("customer {}", customer);
mapperFunction(customerDTO);

        customerRepository.save(customer);

        return customer;

    }

     private void mapperFunction(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {

        Customer customer = customerMapper.customerDTOToCustomer(customerDTO);

        System.out.println(customer);
     }


}
```

and this my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/customerservice")
public class CustomerController {


    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;


    @PostMapping("/newcustomer")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> createCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customer) {
        Customer createdCustomer = customerService.addNewCustomer(customer);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdCustomer);
    }
}
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dbproject</name>
    <description>DB project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version> 
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the fields. It's now not needed when they are parameters of a constructor. 
Also why have you 2 fields with `final` and 1 field (`ObjectMapper`) without? Thus `ObjectMapper` is setter-injected, but the other 2 fields are constructor-injected - because of `@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates only these 2 fields as parameters.

Comment: Also use the latest version of `map-struct`, which is now `1.5.5.Final`. I am not sure about the compatibility.

Comment: You should need to add the `mapstruct-processor` so that it will actually generate code, next ditch the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@ComponentScan` as those aren't needed and might even interfere with detection of classes.

Comment: @HonzaZidek thanks, that solved the problem with your link to the other question, really really strange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpringBoot + Lombok + MapStruct not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685602/springboot-lombok-mapstruct-not-working-together) (I formally voted for closing this question as duplicate, as you confirmed that the linked question solves your problem.

Comment: @HonzaZidek yes

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include the `mapstruct-processor` in your `pom.xml` to generate the mappers at compile time:

- https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#_apache_maven
- https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/

---

If that does not work, you can try defining the bean manually:

```java
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomerMapper customerMapper() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code example but I get a lot of "classnotdefined" exceptions, you know why?

Comment: Including `mapstruct-processor` is a good idea. However, defining the beans manually is *bad* advice indeed - you are suggesting the OP to *hide* the problem, and not to *solve* it.

Comment: @Blnpwr first try including the `mapstruct-processor`. The code snippet was there only to help with debugging once the processor suggestion fails.