# Use Lombok toBuilder when updating an existing bean with MapStruct

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have a class with the following Lombok annotations.

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassA {
  private String id;
  private String a;
  private String b;
}

public class ClassB {
  private String b;
}
```

I need to add a mapping to update an existing instance of ClassA as following :

```java
ClassA update(ClassB b, @MappingTarget ClassA a);
```

The generated mapper is the following, fields gets ignored in the generated mapping, because they don't have setters.

```java
@Override
public ClassA update(ClassB b, ClassA a) {
  if ( b == null ) {
    return a;
  }
 
  return a;
}
```

I tried to use `@BeanMapping(builder = @Builder(buildMethod = "toBuilder"))` but it has no effect.
As ClassA instances are immutable I was expecting MapStruct to have a possibility to make it generate the following code

```
  public ClassA update(ClassB b, ClassA a) {
    if ( b == null ) {
      return a;
    }

    ClassA.ClassABuilder builder = a.toBuilder();
    builder.b(b.getB());
    
    return builder.build();
  }
```

Any tips to make this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instruct Mapstruct to use lombok builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955000/how-to-instruct-mapstruct-to-use-lombok-builder)

Comment: No, My problem was that MapStruct Does not use builder in the generated update methods, I was expecting to have a possibility to do it as class instances may be immutable

Comment: I found that the issue I am describing was already reported here https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2155